# Getting “A generic error occurred in GDI+” when saving image on ASP.NET server by C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gdi+

i have following coding to generate image and than save it my virtual folder "/QRCODE",
but Getting “A generic error occurred in GDI+”

part of my code as below,

```
Bitmap img = encoder.Encode(results);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
int left = (img.Width - logo.Width) / 2;
int top = (img.Height - logo.Height) / 2;
g.DrawImage(logo, new Point(left, top));
img.Save(Server.MapPath("/QRCODE/" + results + ".jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

can anyone suggest where the problem is?

Comment: If you wrap it in an exception handler does the save succeed? I have a very similar issue and I find the exceptions can be ignored.

Comment: Does it happen every time, or just sometimes? Can you post the whole procedure? Do you have any using blocks to release the native handles created, or could it be that you just run out of handles if you call this enough times?

Comment: Try saving a simple text file there, just as a test. Does that work?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't want to use `Server.MapPath("~/QRCODE/" + results + ".jpg")`? And does your application have write access to that folder (by default you don't get write access, for obvious reasons).